# MySQL to MongoDB convert integer IDs to ObjectIDs and rebuild references

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, primary-key, objectid

I am building a new NodeJS application on an existing database. I have converted the existing database from MySQL to MongoDB. I used MySQL Workbench to export the sql data in JSON and then used mongorestore to restore the data to MongoDB. This works.

The existing MySQL database used the autoIncrement property to generate an integer ID number for the primary key.

For example, the "people" table has a primary key "PeopleID", an integer starting from 0 up to about three digits, such as 1, 12, or 123.

Many other tables use this same technique. The "Location" table has a "LocationID" in the same format auto incremented.

In related tables, the primary key is stored as a foreign key, just as a standard relational database.

Here is the newly imported document in MongoDB. Mongo generated an _id for each document.

```
{
    "_id": "5ce89632c15df953bbe163e1", // newly created MongoDB ObjectID
    "PersonID": 1, // old primary key
    "LocationID": 12, // old foreign key
    "FirstName": "John",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Smith"
}
```

I want to rebuild all of the references using ObjectIDs instead of the auto incremented integers. So ideally the new document would look like this, with the "foreign key" as an ObjectID reference.

```
{
    "_id": "5ce89632c15df953bbe163e1", // Use this as the reference instead of the old "PersonID"
    "PersonID": 1, // old primary key
    "LocationID": "5ce8358ec15df953bab163ea", // example ObjectID as a reference
    "FirstName": "John",
    "MiddleName": "",
    "LastName": "Smith"
}
```

Would it be possible to programmatically rebuild the relationships using references with ObjectIDs instead of the old integer values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the references based on the integer foreign keys by writing a set of queries in Mongoose. The first step is to build an array of dictionaries to map each legacy foreign key to its ObjectID. The next step is to iterate over each document in the target collection, for each item, lookup the ObjectID in the `idmap` created previously. The last step is to update the target document with the new ObjectID.

In this case, I created a map of the LocationIDs to ObjectIDs and updated the People collection with the new Location_id. I set it up to work as a GET request in a router. This is a quick solution and only works on one mapping at a time. When I have a chance I can make it more scalable and parameterized and possibly even wrap it into a module. Let me know if anyone thinks this is a useful start. I will continue to use it as necessary for this MySQL to MongoDB migration.

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

/**
 * *** INSTRUCTIONS ***
 *
 * Convert a MySQL relationship to a NoSQL reference
 *
 * People table is the target table that contains the relational primary key PersonID
 * LocationID is a relational foreign key stored as an integer
 * Iterate all documents in People collection
 * Match LocationID integer in the Locations collection to get its unique ObjectID
 * Store the retrieved ObjectID as Location_id in People collection

    MySQL Relationship to convert

    PersonID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true
    },
    LocationID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10).UNSIGNED,
      allowNull: true,
      references: {
        model: 'locations',
        key: 'LocationID'
      }

    MongoDB Reference to create

    // Relational primary key autoIncrement ID
    PersonID: {
      type: Number,
      index: true,
      unique: true
    },
    // Relational foreign key autoIncrement ID
    LocationID: {
      type: Number
    },
    // ObjectID reference
    Location_id: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Locations'
    }

 * People
 * Primary Key table = people
 * Foreign Key table = locations
 * Foreign Key field to convert = LocationID
 * New Foreign Key field  = Location_id
 *
 */

// Perform update if true if false read records and log only
const pktable = require('../../models/people');
const fktable = require('../../models/locations');
const prvfkfield = 'LocationID';
const newfkfield = 'Location_id';

router.get('/_id', (req, res, next) => {
  const origin = 'routes/migrate_id.js GET /';

  // Build a dictionary to map old Foreign Key integer to its ObjectID
  async function migrate() {

    // Initialize array to store map of Foreign Keys to ObjectIDs
    let idmap = [];
    // Initialize integer to store number of targets
    let targetcount = 0;
    // Initialize integer to store number of successful results
    let successcount = 0;
    // Initialize integer to store number of skipped results
    let skippedcount = 0;

    // Create a cursor on Foreign Key table
    const fkcursor = fktable.find({}, {[prvfkfield]: 1}).cursor();

    // Build a map of Foreign Keys to ObjectIDs
    await fkcursor.eachAsync(async function (id) {
      idmap.push(id.toObject());
    });

    // Create a cursor on Primary Key table
    const pkcursor = pktable.find().cursor();

    // Iterate each item in cursor and return target record to update
    await pkcursor.eachAsync(async function (target) {

      // Get Previous Foreign Key
      const prvfk = target[prvfkfield];

      targetcount = targetcount + 1;

      // Get ObjectID mapped to the Previous Foriegn Key field
      let objectid = idmap.find(item => item[prvfkfield] === prvfk);

      if (objectid) {
        // Set ObjectID on target document
        target[newfkfield] = objectid;

        try {
          await target.save();
          successcount = successcount + 1;
        } catch (saveerror) {
          console.error(`ERROR: ${JSON.stringify(saveerror)}`);
        }

      } else {
        skippedcount = skippedcount + 1;
      }

    });

    const result = {
      'idmapcount': idmap.length,
      'targetcount': targetcount,
      'successcount': successcount,
      'skippedcount': skippedcount
    };

    return result;

  }

  migrate().then((result) => {
    res.status(200).send(result);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.error(`migrate failed ${error}`);
    res.status(500).send(`migrate failed ${error}`);
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```